# Spring error related to DataSource while deploying in weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I have a spring based jar program which is running fine from my machine. But the goal is to wrap it up as an enterprise application "ear" and to deploy it to weblogic. Following has been done to achieve it and as mentioned "jar" is running fine from my local machine as java program. When the same id deployed to weblogic, its complaining about Datasource Autowiring.

Created ear project as per http://javahonk.com/create-maven-ear-project-eclipse/

Error is thrown at **StartupListener** on

```
applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
```

Below is the structure and some code snippets

```
Main_Project
|
|- ear_module
        |
        |- src/main/java
                |
                |- StartupListener.java
        |
        |- pom.xml
|
|- jar_module
        |
        |- java clases
        |
        |- pom.xml
|
|- war_module
        |
        |- src/main/java
                |
                |- WebCongig.java
                |
                |- Servlet.java
        |
        |- pom.xml
|
|-pom.xml
```

**StartupListener.java**

```
 applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
 applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("war");
 applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
 applicationContext.refresh();    
 App app = applicationContext.getBean(App.class);
 app.run();
```

**AppConfig.java** in jar

```
@Autowired 
Environment env;
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Bean(destroyMethod="")
@Profile("test")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    LOG.info("Initializing DataSource...");
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("driver"));
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("url"));
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("user"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("password"));
    ds.setInitialSize(2);
    LOG.info("DriverManagerDataSource configured: " + ds.getUrl());
    dataSource = ds;
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Profile("jndi")
public DataSource getJndiDataSource() {
    LOG.info("Lookup JNDI DataSource...");
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(env.getProperty("jndi"));
}
```

**Exception while deploying in Weblogic**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>       at com.abc.startup.StartupListener.postStart(StartupListener.java:27)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$PostStartAction.run(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:309)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.SecurityUtils$WLSSecurityProvider.invokePrivilegedAction(SecurityUtils.java:177)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.SecurityUtils.invokePrivilegedAction(SecurityUtils.java:80)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow$LifecycleListenerAction.invoke(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:200)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.BaseLifecycleFlow.postStart(BaseLifecycleFlow.java:67)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.TailLifecycleFlow.activate(TailLifecycleFlow.java:26)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)

Comment: I suspect that you don't want to autowire your dataSource in the appConfig class. Instead, simply create two @Bean dataSource methods - one for the test profile and another for the default runtime profile.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for getting back quickly, but this didn't work either.